# Protractor e2e test table header and <tr>,<td> tags

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, protractor, e2e-testing

I am using below table. In that I want to test each tag(th, td tags), Text in that tags and count of that text.
**HTML snippet**

```
<table class="table table-striped">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <th><b><a ng-href="" ng-click="predicate='id';reverse=!reverse">Patient Id</a></b></th>
         <th><b><a ng-href="" ng-click="predicate='accountNumber';reverse=!reverse" class="">Account Number</a></b></th>
         <th><b><a ng-href="" ng-click="predicate='title';reverse=!reverse">Title</a></b></th>
         <th><b><a ng-href="" ng-click="predicate='firstName';reverse=!reverse">First Name</a></b></th>
         <th><b><a ng-href="" ng-click="predicate='lastName';reverse=!reverse">Last Name</a></b></th>
         <th><b><a ng-href="" ng-click="predicate='middleName';reverse=!reverse">Middle Name</a></b></th>
         <th><b><a ng-href="" ng-click="predicate='sex';reverse=!reverse">Sex</a></b></th>
         <th><b><a ng-href="" ng-click="predicate='dob';reverse=!reverse">Dob</a></b></th>         
      </tr>

      <tr ng-repeat="listItem in filteredListItems | orderBy:predicate:reverse" ng-class="rowClass(listItem)" class="ng-scope">
         <td class="ng-binding">10</td>
         <td class="ng-binding">Tam</td>
         <td class="ng-binding">Mr.</td>
         <td class="ng-binding">Tam</td>
         <td class="ng-binding">Vinh</td>
         <td class="ng-binding">J.</td>
         <td class="ng-binding">F</td>
         <td class="ng-binding"></td>
         <td><a ng-href="#/detailView/patients/10" href="#/detailView/patients/10">Details</a></td>
         <td><button ng-click="deleteRecord(10)" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Delete</button></td>
      </tr>

     <tr ng-repeat="listItem in filteredListItems | orderBy:predicate:reverse" ng-class="rowClass(listItem)" class="ng-scope">
         <td class="ng-binding">12</td>
         <td class="ng-binding">Tam12</td>
         <td class="ng-binding">Mr.</td>
         <td class="ng-binding">Steve</td>
         <td class="ng-binding">John</td>
         <td class="ng-binding">A.</td>
         <td class="ng-binding">F</td>
         <td class="ng-binding"></td>
         <td><a ng-href="#/detailView/patients/12" href="#/detailView/patients/12">Details</a></td>
         <td><button ng-click="deleteRecord(12)" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Delete</button></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

I tried like this, but it's not working.

```
it('Patient Page text testing', function(){

        var table = element(by.css('.table'));
    var firsttag = table.element(by.tagName('tbody'));
    var secondtag = firsttag.all(by.tagName('tr')).get(0);
    var thirdtag = secondtag.all(by.tagName('th')).get(0);        
     expect(element(by.xpath('//b/a')).getText()).toEqual('Patient Id');
    var thirdtag = secondtag.all(by.tagName('th')).get(1);        
     expect(element(by.xpath('//b/a')).getText()).toEqual('Account Number');
});
```

In the above test, expectation is working but second expectation is not working.

**Error :**

```
Message:
 Expected 'Patient Id' to equal 'Account Number'.
```

Still in the second expectation it is expecting 'Patient Id'. I don't no where I did wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead, find all headers using [`element.all()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder) and use [`map()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.map) to assert the list in one go:

```
var headers = element.all(by.css('table.table th a')).map(function(elm) {
    return elm.getText();
});

expect(headers).toEqual([
    "Patient Id",
    "Account Number",
    "Title",
    "First Name",
    "Last Name",
    "Middle Name",
    "Sex",
    "Dob"
]);
```

Comment: **Count :**                                                                  var list = element.all(by.css('th a'));
     expect(list.count()).toBe(8);

Comment: **Individual Header:**                                                                                                                                                   var test = element.all(by.css('th a')).get(2);
     expect(test.getText()).toBe('Title');