# Protractor E2E Test - How can I get a Table Heading by its repeater?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

Looking at [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27519926/protractor-e2e-test-table-header-and-tr-td-tags), I can get the information for a table heading by it's class/tags. However, for the table I have I would like to get mine using the repeater.

I know I can get the rows using `element.all(by.repeater('row in myRows'))` but that only seems to include the `tr` rows themselves, and not the heading (`th`) row.

How can I use `by.repeater` to get the row of headings?

Comment: Are the `th`s added by the repeater, like the `tr`s?

Comment: Nope, I think that's where my problem lies - this might not even be possible

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to get one repeater row and use [`ancestor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/ancestor) to get the `table` parent element. Then, you can get to the `th` header elements from there:

```
var rows = element.all(by.repeater('row in myRows'));
var table = rows.first().all(by.xpath("ancestor::table")).last();
var headers = table.all(by.tagName("th"));
```

Comment: Hmm, my `headers` array is coming back as empty when I use this

Comment: Getting a `ptor_` object now - is this maybe a promise that needs to be handled first?

Comment: @millerbr `headers` would be an array of elements in your case. Here is an example, how can you check, for instance, header texts: `expect(headers.getText()).toEqual(["Header 1", "Header 2"]);`..hope that helps.

Comment: Ah, what I meant was that `headers` is now being set to the `ptor_` object - which is something I usually see when a promise isn't fulfilled, but in this case I'm not sure

Comment: @millerbr well, sure, everything is a promise in protractor. `headers` is an `ElementArrayFinder` instance which is itself is a promise which can be explicitly or implicitly resolved into an array of elements. Have that `expect()` sample worked for you?

Comment: Ran it just there and getting an error stating `Index out of bound: Trying to access element at index: -1, but there are only 0 elements that match locatior By.tagname("th"`

Comment: @millerbr okay, could you give a quick try to `var table = rows.first().all(by.xpath("ancestor::table")).first();` (first instead of last)?

Comment: Same error but this time trying to access at index 0 instead of 1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104899/discussion-between-alecxe-and-millerbr).